# ASP.NET Core 3.1 with google signin, nginx reverse proxy and docker Resource temporarily unavailable

Tags: c#, docker, asp.net-core, nginx-reverse-proxy

I'm building an ASP.NET Core 3.1 web application with the goal to be hosted on an AWS EC2 instance.

My setup is as follows:

- EC2 instance running Debian 10
- Nginx reverse proxy
- certbot for ssl certificate
- Docker running in swarm mode
- ASP.NET Core 3.1 web application (docker)
- SQL Server database (docker)

The web application and SQL Server database are both running in containers and are described in a docker-compose.yml file:

```
version: '3.5'

services:
  db:
    image: mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2017-latest
    deploy:
      replicas: 1
    environment:
      - ACCEPT_EULA=y
      - SA_PASSWORD=${SA_PASSWORD}
    ports:
      - 1433:1433
    volumes:
      -${MSSQL_STORAGE}:/var/opt/mssql

  ui:
    image: ${PRIVATE_DOCKER_REGISTRY}/${APPLICATION_NAME}/${SERVICE}:${TAG}
    deploy:
      replicas: 1
    ports:
    - 5000:80
    environment:
      ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT: Development
      GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID: ${GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID}
      GOOGLE_SECRET_ID: ${GOOGLE_SECRET_ID}
      DB_HOST: db
      DB_NAME: ${DB_NAME}
      DB_PASSWORD: ${DB_PASSWORD}
      DB_USER: ${DB_USER}
```

My application when running in local debug mode and in a local docker swarm runs as expected (accessed with `http://localhost:5000`). I'm able to log in with my google authentication and I'm redirected to the correct page after login.

When I deploy to the ec2 instance however I'm unable to login.

`docker service logs -tf {service_name}` I see the following:

> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Google.GoogleHandler[4]
>
> Error from RemoteAuthentication: Resource temporarily unavailable.
>
> fail:
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware[1]
>
> An unhandled exception has occurred while executing the request.
> System.Exception: An error was encountered while handling the remote login.
> System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: Resource temporarily unavailable
> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException (11): Resource temporarily unavailable
>
> at System.Net.Http.ConnectHelper.ConnectAsync(String host, Int32 port, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
> --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
> at System.Net.Http.ConnectHelper.ConnectAsync(String host, Int32 port, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
> at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.ConnectAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean allowHttp2, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
> at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.CreateHttp11ConnectionAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
> at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.GetHttpConnectionAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
> at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.SendWithRetryAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean doRequestAuth, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
> at System.Net.Http.RedirectHandler.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
> at System.Net.Http.DiagnosticsHandler.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
> at System.Net.Http.HttpClient.FinishSendAsyncBuffered(Task`1 sendTask, HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationTokenSource cts, Boolean disposeCts)   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OAuth.OAuthHandler`1.ExchangeCodeAsync(OAuthCodeExchangeContext context)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OAuth.OAuthHandler`1.HandleRemoteAuthenticateAsync()   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.RemoteAuthenticationHandler`1.HandleRequestAsync()
> --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.RemoteAuthenticationHandler`1.HandleRequestAsync()
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.EntityFrameworkCore.MigrationsEndPointMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.EntityFrameworkCore.DatabaseErrorPageMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.EntityFrameworkCore.DatabaseErrorPageMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)

My nginx configuration is as follows:

```
server {
        server_name mydomain.com;

        location / {
                proxy_pass         http://127.0.0.1:5000;
                proxy_http_version 1.1;
                proxy_set_header   Upgrade $http_upgrade;
                proxy_set_header   Connection keep-alive;
                proxy_set_header   Host $host;
                proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
                proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        }


    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/mydomain.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/mydomain.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot

}
```

I'm thinking maybe the reverse proxy configuration is incorrect somehow? Incorrect headers maybe or something else?

Answer (score 0):

A common problem with Google Auth when your app is behind a reverse proxy is that the URL doesn't match the URL/domain name you supplied in the Google Developers Console. When using a reverse proxy, you are changing the request URL from mydomain.com to http://127.0.0.1:5000.

Adding the ForwardedHeaders in your code should fix this so the request keeps the original URL as well as the Forwarded Url

```html
      // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            app.UseForwardedHeaders(new ForwardedHeadersOptions
            {
                ForwardedHeaders = ForwardedHeaders.XForwardedProto
            });
            
           // other Configure code here
```